# Need Some help on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am not a professional in `HTML css` and I have a design to convert in `HTML`. I read about canvas but I did'nt get idea that how can I fulfill my requirement. I search a lot but nothing very help full.

Here is my design:
[image]

Its a banner area and have three parts.

> 1. Banner Image (Car Pic)
> 2. Transparent triangle type div
> 3. And there are nav (menus)

I just want to know that how can I create this triangle type `div` because I have no idea.

So please give me a helpful solutions. I am very thank full to you.

**Note:** Its also a responsive.

Comment: you could use 'transform: rotate(12deg);' in your css, but you would have to remember to do the opposite with your text

Comment: I know Im gonna look needy but if my answer seems ok to you, could you accept it maybe? @deemi

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to separate nav from the rotated div, and as @krisph said you just need to apply a transform: rotate(45deg) on that div and leave it fixed. Then apply a transform: rotate(45deg) on each square point. You don't even need to use canvas I guess !